# MobileSim text display not working‏

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using MobileSim 0.5.0 (mobilesim_0.5.0_i386.deb) on Ubuntu 11.10 x86. I have installed these extra packages:

```
libwxgtk2.6-0
libgtk2.0
python-wxgtk2.6
```

I am using ROS electric and the RosAria Stack. When starting MobileSim (MobileSim -r amigo) I get these warnings:

```
(MobileSim:9124): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_alloc_colors: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed



 Warning: Could not load any font. Text display may not work.
```

MobileSim then shows a window whith the robot, but not menu or text. Please see image for how it looks exactly.

Thanks for any help.

[image description http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/%7Ee0102918/Joomla/attachments/article/52/mobilesim.png](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/%7Ee0102918/Joomla/attachments/article/52/mobilesim.png)

BR,

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46909/mobilesim-text-display-not-working%E2%80%8F/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-10-27**:
THis doesn't appear to be ROS-related. That mobilesim deb appears to be provided by http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/MobileSim . Does it work fine on the same machine if you uninstall ROS?

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2013-05-15**:
Omg its a users fault :-). Ubuntu Unity or whats it called, shows the dropdownmenu integrated into the header if the window is maximized. Arg. Please consider this thread as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved according to OP: "Omg its a users fault :-). Ubuntu Unity or whats it called, shows the dropdownmenu integrated into the header if the window is maximized. Arg. Please consider this thread as closed."

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0